# Boolean and of three columns in pandas

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe as shown below

```
ID     F1       F2         F3        
1      True     False      False
2      True     True       True
3      False    False      False
4      True     False      False
5      True     True       True
```

From the above, I want to create new column which will be True if F1, F2 and F3 are True

```
ID     F1       F2         F3        CONSIDER  
1      True     False      False     False
2      True     True       True      True
3      False    False      False     False
4      True     False      False     False
5      True     True       True      True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) with filtered columns in list:

```
df['CONSIDER'] = df[['F1','F2','F3']].all(axis=1)
print (df)
   ID     F1     F2     F3  CONSIDER
0   1   True  False  False     False
1   2   True   True   True      True
2   3  False  False  False     False
3   4   True  False  False     False
4   5   True   True   True      True
```

Comment: can you please print the data frame